# Matlab returns null to .NET instead of .NET object

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I would like to call a Matlab function from a C# client. This Matlab function returns C# objects. But for some reason instead of the object, I get null returned.

What I try:
I have a .dll built in  C#/.NET which contains the definition of class `CalibrationCharacteristics` in a namespace `CalibrationAlgorithm`. In the simplest form it would look like this:

```
public class CalibrationCharacteristics
{
    public bool OverAllPassed;

    public CalibrationCharacteristics()
    {
        OverAllPassed = true;
    }
}
```

I have a Matlab Script which does the following using the built dll:

```
function t = testInterface(rawData)    

NET.addAssembly('[long path here]\TestForMatlab.dll');
t = CalibrationAlgorithm.CalibrationCharacteristics;
t.OverAllPassed = false;
```

I am trying to run the Matlab function from .NET using (as described in the Mathworks documentation: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html)

```
    matlab.Feval("testInterface", 1, out outObject, rawData);
```

But what when I run the program I get `null` for `outObject`.

If I make the Matlab function simpler (e.g. just adding `t=1;` at the end) I get back what I expect (namely 1 in an object).

Am I trying to something that will not work?

Comment: Does it work with a simpler MATLAB function? Like just a simple function that returns the input integer?

Comment: Is matlab installed on the PC where code is being run?  If not do you have same version of RunTime Library that dll was built?  I would put code in a Exception Handler (Try/Catch) and get the StackTrace to find root cause of issue.

Comment: CalibrationCharacteristics is not a static object, this needs to be newed somewhere to return its instance. I do not see it has been instantiated.

Comment: @Jegan: In my understanding the object is instantiated in Matlab with t = CalibrationAlgorithm.CalibrationCharacteristics; Do I have to do this in C# as well?

Comment: I believe that what @Jegan means is that you should do something like `t = new CalibrationAlgorithm.CalibrationCharacteristics();`

Comment: @Alicia: This won't work in Matlab. But in my knowledge `t = CalibrationAlgorithm.CalibrationCharacteristics;` already instantiates an object. This is a bit sloppy in Matlab, because the brackets can be ommited. Even with brackets I don't get what I expect.